# Replacing href link with jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, html, liquid

I want to replace my href with jquery

I know there's a lot about this on the internet, but it just won't work for me.
I work with liquid, and I have investigated whether that is the problem, but that is not the case

I now have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets"]').each(function(){ 
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter/page/", "https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter?page="); // Create new url
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set new href value
    });
});
```

This is supposed to work, at least it works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9qdxcyo4/).

Here a part of my HTML, Hope it's enough

```
{% for part in paginate.parts %}
      {% if part.is_link %}
        <li>
          <a rel="prev start" href="{{ part.url }}" id="page-number">
            {{ part.title }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        {% if part.title == paginate.current_page %}
          <li class="active" id="page-number">
            {{ part.title }}
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li>
            <a rel="start" id="page-number"> {{ part.title }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Can someone help me get this working?

**Edit 1**

I should have said that I use Freshdesk

**Edit 2**

Result i get from the HTML:

```
<li>
   <a rel="prev start" href="/support/tickets/filter/page/2?requested_by=0&amp;url_locale=&amp;wf_filter=all" id="page-number">
            2
          </a>
</li>
```

**Edit 3**

Okay I have to be a lot clearer. I will explain the whole problem well.

I use Freshdesk to create a support site, Freshdesk uses liquid (with which I now make a pagination) but I get the wrong link to go to the next page.

Freshdesk tells me to solve this with jquery but I don't want to succeed

I will now just add a snippet (and hope that the error will also come here)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="/support/tickets/page/"]').each(function() {
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/support/tickets/page/", "/support/tickets?page="); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
      <ul>
        
          <li class="disabled">
            <span class="disabled">« Previous </span>
          </li>
        

        
          
            
              <li>
                <a rel="start" id="page-number"> 1</a>
              </li>
            
          
        
          
            <li>
              <a rel="prev start" href="/support/tickets/page/2?url_locale=" id="page-number">
                2
              </a>
            </li>
          
        

        
          <li class="next_page">
            <a rel="next" href="/support/tickets/page/2?url_locale=">
              Next »
            </a>
          </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: If it works in the fiddle, then the problem is in your page. Have you checked that the selector is matching any elements? It's also worth noting that client-side JS is just about the last place you should be making this change. Do it wherever the `part.url` value is stored.

Comment: use id selector

Comment: *"at least it works here"* - Can you provide an example where it doesn't work?  Your "HTML" is more template than result and doesn't show us what your JavaScript code would be seeing.

Comment: Perhaps the html that needs to be replaced is brought in by an asynchronous javascript call that runs after page load.  If that is the case, the horse is before the cart _(the replacement is happening before the ajax content arrives)_.

Comment: @David It is a page that only customers can access. So I'm afraid I can't give an example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't store it myself, Freshdesk does that. So unfortunately I can't get to it

Comment: @WimTH: If *even you* can't access an instance of this page to observe the resulting HTML then it's going to be extremely difficult for you to fix it for whoever owns it.

Comment: @David Oh wait, I misunderstood you. Is a video of the result enough?

Comment: @WimTH: Why a video?  HTML is text.  You can edit the question to add more text (formatted as code of course).

Comment: @David I added the result

Comment: @WimTH: Your jQuery selector is looking for an `href` that starts with `"https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets"`.  The `href` in your HTML doesn't start with that.

Comment: @David wow, that's very stupid of me. Let me check if it works now

Comment: this is a server side issue...solving client side is a hack.  the link should be replaced using `liquid` before ever showing up in the end html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for links that start with a specific value:

```
$('a[href^="https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets"]')
```

But your link doesn't start with that value:

```
<a rel="prev start" href="/support/tickets/filter/page/2?requested_by=0&amp;url_locale=&amp;wf_filter=all" id="page-number">
```

Remove the `"https://support.beefinity.com"` from your selector and string manipulation logic and [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/vn7hmd16/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="/support/tickets/filter/page/"]').each(function() {
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/support/tickets/filter/page/", "/support/tickets/filter?page="); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
  });
});
```

**Edit:** It looks like you also need to update the URL to replace the original `?` specifier with an `&`, since you're adding a new `?`.  Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltncxbrp/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="/support/tickets/filter/page/"]').each(function() {
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("?", "&");
    newUrl = newUrl.replace("/support/tickets/filter/page/", "/support/tickets/filter?page="); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
  });
});
```

Comment: @WimTH: Can you be more specific?  Please update the question to demonstrate the exact problem you're facing.  Since it's just HTML and JavaScript, you can even add to the question a runnable code snippet to observe the problem directly.

Comment: I have updated the post again, it looks like he's doing it wrong again. I see your edit and I didn't think of it, thank you for thinking along!

Comment: @WimTH: The URLs in your updated example have again changed to not match the jQuery selector.  It's exactly as the previous problem, just repeated.  In order to select the elements based on the URL you need to know what the URL is.

Comment: Okay I just found out that that link is constantly changing

Comment: After endlessly changing those links, I finally succeeded. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since jquery isn't working, the better solution is to use [`liquid` to do the replacement](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/replace/).  For instance:

```
{{ "Take my protein pills and put my helmet on" | replace: "my", "your" }}
```

would produce

> Take your protein pills and put your helmet on

Change your template to do the replacement before the HTML is produced:

```
{% for part in paginate.parts %}
      {% if part.is_link %}
        <li>
          <a rel="prev start" href="{{ part.url | replace: "support/tickets/filter/page/", "support/tickets/filter?page=" }}" id="page-number">
            {{ part.title }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        {% if part.title == paginate.current_page %}
          <li class="active" id="page-number">
            {{ part.title }}
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li>
            <a rel="start" id="page-number"> {{ part.title }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to point at an issue with your code:
Your jsfiddle code is not correct:
Old URL:

```
<a rel="prev start" href="https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter/page/2?requested_by=0&url_locale=&wf_filter=all" id="page-number">2</a>
```

New URL after replacing:

```
<a rel="prev start" href="https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter?page=2?requested_by=0&url_locale=&wf_filter=all2?requested_by=0&url_locale=&wf_filter=all" id="page-number">2</a>
```

Secondly, it could be like your DOM is not ready when you jQuery script goes through. That means jQuery may not have found any "A" tags with selector. Try adding console log.

Comment: Yes this could be it, I have added console log but I don't see it. How could I solve this?

Comment: I have added answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make sure you fix url looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').on('click','a[href^="https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets"]', function(){
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter/page/", "https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter?page="); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl).click(); // Set new href value
    location.href = newUrl;
});
```

});